# How to replace sqlite file with the new one if I use core data?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I am currently working on the app that is going to use database to store items. The first thing that everybody say, when it comes to store data in iOS is Core Data.

But, after few days of looking through tutorials and docs, I have a big question.

Let me explain architecture a little bit more. So we have a backend, where you can add items, also, we have iOS and Android application. I am creating a Core Data model for our database.
What we want,is to check if there is update for database and download it. The problem is that we don't use JSON or XML, we are using the new sqlite file.

Since Core data creates three files for database, which are:

- db.sqlite
- db.sqlite-wal
- db.sqlite-shm

Is core data able to replace "db.sqlite" with the new one, that is downloaded from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought the idea of replacing the database file instead of importing objects to it is very tempting it's highly discouraged to mess up with sqlite database created by CoreData. You should never touch it manually, when you do, you'll very likely end up with broken DB or messed up data.
So no, CoreDate is not able to replace underlaying sqlite file. You should instead import your data using CoreData stack, that's how it's designed. Creating JSON/XML service is the best way you can go.

BUT **IN THEORY** and in case you would be able to keep CD internal information stored in the db untouched, it should be possible to replace the sqlite file. If your database is read-only for users, it ***might*** work, but if users are able to create or modify records, forget about it right now.

First, you'd have to tear down all CoreData stacks (Managed Object Context, Persistent Store Coordinator, Managed Object Model) that might be using it before you replace it, replace the file and re-create CoreData stack(s).

db.sqlite is the main database file, the other two are temporary files, Write ahead log (wal) and Shared memory (smh), so you don't need these two.

Remember you never **MUST NOT** change the structure of the database, just data in it!

However, as stated in the beginning, I ***do not*** recommend this approach at all.

Comment: Thank you, very much! You confirmed my thoughts.

Comment: Is it a **bad practice** also for a "Backup strategy"?

Comment: I'd say yes, it is a bad practice. For example, structure of the db file can change with new OS releases, so if you replace it with older version, your app could render unusable.

Comment: can you quote any resources to support the answer?